# No latin signs Symfony2/Bootstrap3

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

im using symfony2(twig) with bootstrap3 and the problem is - i dont have latin signs. Wherever i use ą ć ó ś ń i got ? ? ? ? ? instead.

My head looks like this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Cztery Ściany{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

When i do normal html(out of the bootstrap3/symfony) with header, it will display the signs i want.

Is there any simple solution to my problem?

Comment: make sure your php file are saved in utf8 format too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out it with help of my fellow mate Pipe.

If you are using php storm, then change the File Encoding to UTF-8. 
Mine was default ISO-8859-1.